# MySQL query using concat and union not working

Tags: mysql, union, concatenation

Hi poeple am trying to get a list of records into one table for a search feature i am doing for a site

the 3 tables are one for page information, 1 for projects and 1 for latest news.

however i am getting an error in my query and i cant see whats wrong with it.

```
SELECT 'section' AS colTYPE, title_sec AS title,
CONCAT_WS(' ',contentcol1_sec, contentcol2_sec, contentcol3_sec) AS content, 
active_sec AS active 
    FROM sections_sec 
    WHERE content LIKE 'fff' OR title LIKE 'fff' AND active = 1) 
    UNION(SELECT 'latest' AS colTYPE, title_lat AS title,
    content_lat AS content, active_lat AS active 
    FROM latest_lat
    WHERE content LIKE 'fff' OR title LIKE 'fff' AND active = 1) 
    UNION(SELECT 'project' AS colTYPE, title_prj AS title, 
    content_prj AS content,     active_prj AS active 
    FROM projects_prj 
    WHERE content LIKE 'fff' OR title LIKE 'fff' AND active = 1)
```

the error i am reciving is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') 
    UNION(SELECT 'latest' AS colTYPE, title_lat AS title, 
content_lat AS conten' at line 3
```

Comment: Why you put ) before first union? Error code say that your syntax is not correct in that's code. > You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that > corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ') > UNION(SELECT 'latest' AS colTYPE, title_lat AS title, content_lat AS conten' at line 3

Answer (score 2):

Your first statement doesn't have an open parentheses. It's typically not necessary to encase your statements in parentheses for a `UNION`

Are you also sure you don't want to be using `UNION ALL`?

```
SELECT 'section'
           AS colTYPE, 
       title_sec
           AS title, 
       Concat_ws(' ', contentcol1_sec, contentcol2_sec, contentcol3_sec)
           AS content, 
       active_sec
           AS active 
FROM   sections_sec 
WHERE  content LIKE 'fff' 
        OR title LIKE 'fff' 
           AND active = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'latest'    AS colTYPE, 
       title_lat   AS title, 
       content_lat AS content, 
       active_lat  AS active 
FROM   latest_lat 
WHERE  content LIKE 'fff' 
        OR title LIKE 'fff' 
           AND active = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'project'   AS colTYPE, 
       title_prj   AS title, 
       content_prj AS content, 
       active_prj  AS active 
FROM   projects_prj 
WHERE  content LIKE 'fff' 
        OR title LIKE 'fff' 
           AND active = 1
```

Comment: Ive just come across union from reading another thread here, whats the diffirence between union all and union?

Comment: am still getting an error: Unknown column 'content' in 'where clause'

Comment: Both stack your results. `UNION` will also remove duplicates, which takes more time.

Comment: @DizzyBryanHigh I don't know what your table schema is, so I can't help you with the `content` column. The error typically means that column doesn't exist.

Comment: If you need to filter based on the result of the concat, you have to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: I tried that Barmar but still getting the same error
@njk: The schema should be whatever i choose for the AS i would have thought
so when i do the Where comparison i should use the AS name or the original column name?

Comment: @Barmar yes it is working with HAVING, i needed to put that instead of where in all of the definitions

Comment: @Barmar Can you please put you comment as an answer its the only reponse that fixed my problem, and i would like to mark this question complete.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `WHERE` clause is closing a parenthesis `)` without a matching open parenthesis!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 'section' AS colTYPE, title_sec AS title, CONCAT_WS(' ',contentcol1_sec, contentcol2_sec, contentcol3_sec) AS content, active_sec AS active 
    FROM sections_sec 
    WHERE (content LIKE 'fff' OR title LIKE 'fff') AND active = 1
    UNION SELECT 'latest' AS colTYPE, title_lat AS title, content_lat AS content, active_lat AS active 
    FROM latest_lat
    WHERE (content LIKE 'fff' OR title LIKE 'fff') AND active = 1 
    UNION SELECT 'project' AS colTYPE, title_prj AS title, content_prj AS content, active_prj AS active 
    FROM projects_prj 
    WHERE (content LIKE 'fff' OR title LIKE 'fff') AND active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first subquery you have to use HAVING, so that you can match against a computed value. In the other subqueries, you need to use the column in the WHERE clause rather than the alias.

```
SELECT 'section' AS colTYPE, title_sec AS title,
CONCAT_WS(' ',contentcol1_sec, contentcol2_sec, contentcol3_sec) AS content, 
active_sec AS active 
FROM sections_sec 
HAVING content LIKE 'fff' OR title LIKE 'fff' AND active = 1
UNION
SELECT 'latest' AS colTYPE, title_lat AS title,
content_lat AS content, active_lat AS active 
FROM latest_lat
WHERE content_lat LIKE 'fff' OR title_lat LIKE 'fff' AND active_lat = 1
UNION
SELECT 'project' AS colTYPE, title_prj AS title, 
content_prj AS content, active_prj AS active 
FROM projects_prj 
WHERE content_prj LIKE 'fff' OR title_prj LIKE 'fff' AND active_prj = 1
```

Also, make sure you understand the precedence of a mixture of AND and OR in a conditional expression. `x OR y OR z` is parsed as `x OR (y AND z)`, not `(x OR y) AND z`.